# Changing fake web cam file (.y4m) device name using Chrome, Selenium, and Python

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, webcam

I am trying to open up Chrome with a fake web cam file which is .y4m as the following:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager as cdm


service = Service(cdm().install())
options = Options()
options.add_argument("--use-fake-device-for-media-stream")
options.add_argument("--use-file-for-fake-video-capture=fake_web_cam.y4m")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
```

It totally works, but the problem is when selecting this cam in some website, the cam name is the same as the path of the .y4m file. I searched a lot but did not find a solution for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it's not possible. By looking at Chromium source you will find out why.

This [link](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/) contains most common Chrome arguments and their references in the source code. if you click on `--use-file-for-fake-video-capture`, it opens [media_switches.cc](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:media/base/media_switches.cc?q=kUseFakeDeviceForMediaStream&ss=chromium). Check it's references and you see there is a function `GetFilePathFromCommandLine` in [file_video_capture_device_factory.cc](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:media/capture/video/file_video_capture_device_factory.cc;l=22;drc=eef4762779d05708d5dfc7d5fe4ea16288069a35) :

```cpp
base::FilePath GetFilePathFromCommandLine() {
  base::FilePath command_line_file_path =
      base::CommandLine::ForCurrentProcess()->GetSwitchValuePath(
          switches::kUseFileForFakeVideoCapture);
  return command_line_file_path;
}
```

By checking references of this function you see this code at the same file:

```cpp
devices_info.emplace_back(
      VideoCaptureDeviceDescriptor(GetFilePathFromCommandLine().AsUTF8Unsafe(),
                                   kFileVideoCaptureDeviceName, api));
```

`VideoCaptureDeviceDescriptor` is defined in [video_capture_device_descriptor.cc](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:media/capture/video/video_capture_device_descriptor.cc;drc=eef4762779d05708d5dfc7d5fe4ea16288069a35;bpv=0;bpt=1;l=24) as follows:

```cpp
VideoCaptureDeviceDescriptor::VideoCaptureDeviceDescriptor(
    const std::string& display_name,
    const std::string& device_id,
    VideoCaptureApi capture_api,
    const VideoCaptureControlSupport& control_support,
    VideoCaptureTransportType transport_type)
    : device_id(device_id),
      facing(VideoFacingMode::MEDIA_VIDEO_FACING_NONE),
      capture_api(capture_api),
      transport_type(transport_type),
      display_name_(TrimDisplayName(display_name)),
      control_support_(control_support) {}
```

So, the file path is given as `display_name` by default and there is no way to change it.

You can use other alternatives to create a virtual webcam from a video file e.g. OBS Studio, SplitCam.